# AJAX request working but not displaying anything?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm having an issue with an ajax request. I have a created a quiz which goes through questions and when the user finishes it, it should call a request to an **ajax.php** file to call out information. Please see my code below, i have run the **ajax.php** file and it is gathering up all the information. But in the **tests.php** page, when it finishes it shows nothing. also the ajax `$("#quiz_form,#demo1").addClass("hide")` seems to work as nothing displays, but doesnt complete the next two functions below.

Can someone help?

Comment: What is the returned data in the request (check your console/network tab)?

Comment: Nothing is in the console? but you can see from network that the ajax.php is called

Comment: _you can see from network that the ajax.php_ I can't see anything. Check the response or post a screenshot of it IN the question.

Comment: Check json_encode and json_decode and in your ajax.php you should use one of these like that echo json_encode()/decode(); exit; I don’t tell you what actually u must use just because i want from you to go and check them and after that you will find out where was your problem

Comment: @SiderTopalov Thanks for that. did that and its bringing me back internal server error? jquery-1.10.0.min.js:6 POST /ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-1.10.0.min.js:6
ajax @ jquery-1.10.0.min.js:6
submit @ tests.php:46
(anonymous) @ tests.php:67
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ tests.php:66
c @ jquery-1.10.0.min.js:4
fireWith @ jquery-1.10.0.min.js:4
ready @ jquery-1.10.0.min.js:4
q @ jquery-1.10.0.min.js:4

Comment: "also the ajax $("#quiz_form,#demo1").addClass("hide") seems to work " well that is NOT ajax just jQuery

Comment: Check my answer and after do change then go in javascript and console.log(msg) and comment other lines inside success function

Comment: Did you try `$('#result').html(msg);`

Comment: @AllenKing yes tried this,still not working :(

Comment: Did you try `alert(msg)` to check if data is actually getting there?

Comment: yeah i did it alerts back what should be outputted on the screen?

Comment: Was better question with code, now NOT.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax.php change this

```
echo "<div id='answer'>";
 echo " Right Answer  : <span class='highlight'>". $right_answer."</span><br>";

 echo " Wrong Answer  : <span class='highlight'>". $wrong_answer."</span><br>";

 echo " Unanswered Question  : <span class='highlight'>". $unanswered."</span><br>";
 echo "</div>";
```

To this:

```
$response = array(
    'right_answer' => $right_answer,
    'wrong_answer' => $wrong_answer,
    'unanswered' => $unanswered
);

echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

And read about json_encode/json_decode

In your ajax change this:

```
success: function(msg) {
   $("#quiz_form,#demo1").addClass("hide");
   $('#result').show();
   $('#result').append(msg);
}
```

with this

```
success: function(data) {
   data = JSON.parse(data);
   var output = "Right Answer: "+data.right_answer + 
            "<br />Wrong Answer: " + data.wrong_answer + 
            "<br />Unanswered Question: "+ data.unanswered;
   $("#quiz_form,#demo1").addClass("hide");
   $('#result').show();
   $('#result').append(output);
}
```

html code should look something like that

```
<div id="question_<?php echo $result['id'];?>" class='questions'></div>
<h2 id="question_<?php echo $result['id'];?>"><?php echo $result['id'].".".$result["question_name"];?></h2>
<div class='align'>
    <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'>
    <label id='ans1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' for='1'><?php echo $result['answer1'];?></label>
    <br/>
</div>
<div id="result" style="display:none;"></div>
```

This should work try to understand code

Comment: This works ok and comes back with right answer but still isnt being outputted on the page?

Comment: Yes of course you need to console.log(msg) inside success function and then modified your code there because you cant append json object to div u need append string not object

Comment: sorry im a beginner, i don't quite get what you mean?

Comment: Right now you are doing this for example .append({a: 1, b:2...}); and the right way is for example this .append(“appended text to element”);

Comment: im sorry im still not getting, can you give me example?

Comment: I update my answer check it and try to understand why your old code doesn't work

Comment: Okay i get it now, but still nothing is being outputted on screen? :(

Comment: yep, here: {"\u2018right_answer\u2019":0,"\u2018wrong_answer\u2019":2,"\u2018unanswered\u2019":0}

Comment: Okay i got it that's my bad cuz i leave you the answer from my phone i update my answer check $response = array(
    'right_answer' => $right_answer,
    'wrong_answer' => $wrong_answer,
    'unanswered' => $unanswered
); and make sure is the same as your

Comment: Ok so..{"right_answer":1,"wrong_answer":1,"unanswered":0} now?

Comment: still not outputting on screen??

Comment: update your question and show me html code probably there is a problem with your html

Comment: OK Done @SiderTopalov

Comment: Bro your html is so wrong.. you don't even had element with id='result' how do you expect to work.. i update my answer check it now

Comment: For me this working perfectly problem is in your html for sure

Comment: Have you got this on fiddle or anything that i can see?

Answer (score 0):

update your codes with following one,

replace your `ajax`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(response){
        $("#quiz_form,#demo1").addClass("hide");
        $('#result').show();
        $('#result').append(response);
    }
});
```

now remove all `echo` in `ajax.php` add add following codes after `while` loop `}` close

```
$html = "<div id='answer'>"+
"Right Answer  : <span class='highlight'>". $right_answer."</span><br>"+
"Wrong Answer  : <span class='highlight'>". $wrong_answer."</span><br>"+
"Unanswered Question  : <span class='highlight'>". $unanswered."</span><br>"+
"</div>";
echo $html;
exit();
```

Comment: Tried this although still not working and now returning {return: 2}
return
:
2

Comment: replace your ajax now and check it, i have updated the ajax with `dataType: "json",`

Comment: now getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1